# If statement triggers an unwanted breakpoint

Tags: c

I want to scan the input of the user, store it in a char array and check if it's an alpha or not.
But it appears an error:

```
Program: 
...\Projects\Testing\Testing\Debug\Testing.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\convert\isctype.cpp
Line: 36

Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

I clicked on "Retry" and then it went to the line where the error come from. It says "Testing.exe triggers breakpoint."

My code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <Windows.h>    
#include <ctype.h>      

int sleep_seconds = 1 * 1000;

int main(void) {

    int while_bool = 1;

    while (while_bool == 1) {

        char kapital_str[100];
        double kapital;     

        printf("\nBitte geben Sie das Kapital (Anfangskapital) in CHF an: ");
        scanf("%s", &kapital_str);
        Sleep(sleep_seconds);
        
        if (isalpha(kapital_str)) {  // <- "Testing.exe triggers breakpoint"
            printf("\nFalsche Eingabe! Bitte beachten Sie, dass es sich um eine Zahl handeln muss");
        }
        else {
            scanf("%lf", &kapital);
   } 
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 19

Comment: There is no line 36 in the code in the question, and there is nothing named `c`. Are you sure you pasted the same code that causes the message? Or is that the output from some test suite that is testing the program you wrote?

Comment: yeah, it jumps to the line where the if statement is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The assertion is triggered in `isctype.cpp`, which is apparently part of the CRT implementation.

Comment: `kapital_str` is an array of `char`, which is automatically converted to `char *` when used as an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`. The argument to `isalpha` should be an `unsigned char` value, that is, a single character, not a pointer to characters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It was a pop up window with the debug error. When I click on "Retry" it jumps to the line, where the error come from. And I can only use isalpha for a single character? But the error appears directly after I clicked on the debug button. I didn't typed anything but the error appears tho.

Comment: `if (isalpha(kapital_str))` should be flagged by the compiler and fixed before you run the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `isalpha()` takes a char (char is also a int) and not a array of char and you have a missing `}`, so the code will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
#include <Windows.h>  

#define MAX_CHAR_LEN 100

int main(void) {

    double kapital;     
    char kapital_str[MAX_CHAR_LEN];

    int while_bool = 1;
    while (while_bool) {

        printf("\nBitte geben Sie das Kapital (Anfangskapital) in CHF an: ");
        scanf_s("%s", &kapital_str, MAX_CHAR_LEN);
        
        int f_not_alph = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < strlen(kapital_str); i++){
            if (isalpha(kapital_str[i])) {
                f_not_alph = 1;
            } 
        }

        if (f_not_alph) {
            printf("Falsche Eingabe! Bitte beachten Sie, dass es sich um eine Zahl handeln muss \n");
        } else {
            sscanf_s((const char*)&kapital_str, "%lf", &kapital);
            printf("Correct -> %lf \n", kapital);
        } 

        f_not_alph = 0;
    }
}
```

Also i would prefer is the comets where on english so i can understand easier what the code is doing.

Comment: okay, thank you! One question: what does the the code in the else codeblock?

Comment: if the text is correct `sscanf_s()` will take the saved text in `kapital_str` with `sscanf_s(char_buffer, format, output_var)` and return it to kapital, and then print a confirmation that the double was saved, i use `_s` functions because the normals always give wanings.

Comment: Yes, `ato*somthing*()` works well, as long as you like how the code works and it makes the job its fine but there are some common complaints about the consistency of that function(s), just take in account what the functions are capable of.